# Call to undefined method Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel::create() in Laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, maatwebsite-excel

I am using Laravel 5.8 and maatwebsite/excel 3.1 to export to Excel but got an error.

> Call to undefined method Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel::create()

I have written export code in Controller and View

config/app.php

```
        /*
         * Package Service Providers...
         */
Maatwebsite\Excel\ExcelServiceProvider::class, 

//Class Aliases
'Excel' => Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel::class,
```

Controller

```
use Excel;

     public function msisdnExport() 
    {
     $msisdns = User::select( 
               "phone"
             )       
               ->get();  

     // Initialize the array which will be passed into the Excel
     // generator.
     $msisdnsArray = []; 

     // Define the Excel spreadsheet headers
     $msisdnsArray[] = ['MSISDN'];

     // Convert each member of the returned collection into an array,
     // and append it to the payments array.
     foreach ($msisdns as $msisdn) {
          $msisdnsArray[] = $msisdn->toArray();
     }

     // Generate and return the spreadsheet
    // Excel::create('MSISDN', function($excel) use ($msisdnsArray) {
        Excel::download('MSISDN', function($excel) use ($msisdnsArray) {

          // Set the spreadsheet title, creator, and description
          $excel->setTitle('MSISDN');
          $excel->setCreator('Developers')->setCompany('Cloud Africa');
          $excel->setDescription('users msisdn file');

          // Build the spreadsheet, passing in the payments array
          $excel->sheet('sheet1', function($sheet) use ($msisdnsArray) {
               $sheet->fromArray($msisdnsArray, null, 'A1', false, false);
          });

     })->download('xlsx');
}
```

View

```
<a href="{{ route('msisdn-export') }}" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" style="margin-right: 15px;"><i class="fa fa-file-excel-o"></i> Excel</a>
```

When I click on Excel in view, it suppose to export to excel but got this error.

> Call to undefined method Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel::create()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `create` method has been removed. You have to use one of the following:

```
Excel::download($yourExport);
Excel::store($yourExport);
```

As stated in the upgrade guide:

> Excel::create() is removed and replaced by Excel::download/Excel::store($yourExport)

Source: https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/getting-started/upgrade.html#upgrading-to-3-from-2-1

Comment: I changed it but got another error.   >Argument 2 passed to Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel::download() must be of the type string, object given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\reporting-soccerrave\vendor\laravel.   See the update

Comment: @user11352561 Did you read the upgrade guide? You cannot simply rename the function. Have a look at this here: https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel/issues/1799